# Reuse annotation in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation

Every year I spent lot of time manually adjusting annotation labels for our 2018 stations (250+ points & labels in a A4 page). To save effort, I want to reuse most of these labels for 2019.

Can I join 2019 station point features and copy/save the 2018 annotation labels as 2019 labels and add/drop labels; few stations get removed or few new ones added?

Comment: Are you creating "[feature-linked](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/about-editing-feature-linked-annotation.htm)" annotation or a standalone annotation feature class?

Comment: Looks like annotation feature class? Data Type: File Geodatabase Feature Class, Database: T:\data\Sites.gdb, Feature Class: Stations2018Anno, Feature Type:Annotation, Geometry Type: Polygon